# NodeJS UTF8 String appears as ?? instead of emoji

Tags: mysql, node.js, emoji

I have a value in a MySQL row that says "Testing" and has a thumbs up emoji: 
[image]

But when I retrieve this value from the database I get this output in the console:

[image]

What can I do to make emoji work within NodeJS?

```
                    database.query({
                        sql: "SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 250"
                    }, function(error, results) {
                        if (error) {
                            errorLog("MySQL error: " + error.code);
                        } else {
                            var messages = [];
                            results.forEach(function(result) {
                                console.log("pushing with msg " + result.message);
                                messages.push({userID: String(result.sender), name: String(result.senderName), message: String(result.message)});
                            });
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution after playing around with various settings. When you connect to the MySQL server, you must specify the preference `charset: 'utf8mb4'` like so:

```
var database = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'account',
    password: '1234',
    database: 'database',
    charset: 'utf8mb4'
});
```